# RSA Encryption with JWK in Postman Pre-Request Script

Tags: javascript, postman, rsa

I've got public key information exposed by a service as a JWK, .e.g:

```
{
    "keys": [
        {
            "kty": "RSA",
            "e": "AQAB",
            "use": "enc",
            "kid": "7a1571d1-c1f9-0afd-4c0e-a25a06a53b19",
            "n": "jDUql9BJZL....._wz75nYbRKbXs8UBw"
        }
    ]
}
```

Now I'm struggling on doing the asymmetric encryption in a postman script with the public key due to the limited options on using external libraries. It's fairly easy to do with [node-jose](https://github.com/cisco/node-jose) (see code below), but I seem not find a solution for postman.

```
// node example
let encrypted = await jose.JWE.createEncrypt({ format: 'compact' }, <KEY-FROM-JWK-RESPONSE>)
  .update(jose.util.asBuffer(<TO_ENCRYPT>))
  .final()
  .then(result => {
    return result
  }).catch(error => {
    console.log(`Error encrypting the value: ${error}`)
  }) as string
```

I've tried several approaches:

- using some external lib like [jose](https://github.com/panva/jose) from CDN & using `eval` to make it available in postman, but didn't succeed due to different errors
- using the [postman util lib](https://joolfe.github.io/postman-util-lib/): I'm able to integrate via `eval` but can't figure out on how to use the JWK for encryption

Any code snippets, documentation or general tips are highly appreciated.

Comment: coul;d you add more information on what kind of encryption you are trying , postman supports cryptojs